# How to select one specific element (div) from many elements with same class name in with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got problem targeting specific div that share same class name. In the code below, I am hiding all the divs in the css file, but i am displaying them in the jQuery script. But, instead of showing all of them, I want to show only one specific div, but I don't want to use div's specific ID. My point is to make for loop where I will rotate which div will be displayed.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  let divs = $('.divs');
    
  divs.css('display', 'block');

});
```

```css
#div1 {
 background-color: rgb(246, 210, 88);
}

#div2 {
 background-color: rgb(239, 206, 197);
}

#div3 {
 background-color: rgb(136, 177, 75);
}

#div4 {
 background-color: rgb(151, 213, 224);
}

#div5 {
 background-color: rgb(239, 86, 45);
}

.divs {
 width: 300px;
 height: 300px;
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
   <title>Slider Exercise</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>

   <div class="divs" id="div1"></div>
   <div class="divs" id="div2"></div>
   <div class="divs" id="div3"></div>
   <div class="divs" id="div4"></div>
   <div class="divs" id="div5"></div>


   
   <!-- Scripts -->
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="viktor.js"></script>

  </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: you probably dont come around adding and removing an "active-class" or attribute for the specific div

Comment: What event are using to determine which div to show?

Answer (score 2):

You mean to do something like this?:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  let divs = $('.divs');
  let i = 0;

  setInterval(function() {
    divs.hide();
    $(divs[i++]).show();
    if (i >= divs.length)
        i = 0;
  }, 1000);

});
```

```css
#div1 {
 background-color: rgb(246, 210, 88);
}

#div2 {
 background-color: rgb(239, 206, 197);
}

#div3 {
 background-color: rgb(136, 177, 75);
}

#div4 {
 background-color: rgb(151, 213, 224);
}

#div5 {
 background-color: rgb(239, 86, 45);
}

.divs {
 width: 300px;
 height: 300px;
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
   <title>Slider Exercise</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>

   <div class="divs" id="div1"></div>
   <div class="divs" id="div2"></div>
   <div class="divs" id="div3"></div>
   <div class="divs" id="div4"></div>
   <div class="divs" id="div5"></div>


   
   <!-- Scripts -->
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="viktor.js"></script>

  </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: I want to ask, what is that 1000 at end of the function :)? (i am beginner)

Comment: It's the repeating time, in milliseconds (it's repeating again after 1 second) and it fires multiple times as I'm using setInterval instead of setTimeout.

Answer (score 1):

*«My point is to make for loop where I will rotate which div will be displayed.»*

Something like this?

The trick is to  hide all `.divs`. Then shows only one, based on a counter. The [`.eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) method is used.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  var i=0;
  var divs = $('.divs');
  
  divs.eq(0).show();
  
  $("#previous,#next").on("click",function(){
  
    divs.hide();
    if( $(this).attr("id")=="next" ){
      i++;
      i = (i>=divs.length) ? 0 : i;
    }else{
      i--;
      i = (i<0) ? divs.length-1 : i;
    }
    console.log(i);
    divs.eq(i).show();
  });

});
```

```css
#div1 {
  background-color: rgb(246, 210, 88);
}

#div2 {
  background-color: rgb(239, 206, 197);
}

#div3 {
  background-color: rgb(136, 177, 75);
}

#div4 {
  background-color: rgb(151, 213, 224);
}

#div5 {
  background-color: rgb(239, 86, 45);
}

.divs {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="previous">Previous</button>
<button id="next">Next</button>
      
<div class="divs" id="div1"></div>
<div class="divs" id="div2"></div>
<div class="divs" id="div3"></div>
<div class="divs" id="div4"></div>
<div class="divs" id="div5"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to change which div is displayed randomly at a set interval you can use a combination of `Math.random()` and the `setInterval` function.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  var divs = $('.divs');
  var index;
  
  // runs every second
  setInterval(function(){
    // get a random whole number (may get the same random number consecutively)
   index = Math.floor(Math.random() * divs.length);
    divs.css('display', 'none');                // hide all divs
   $(divs[index]).css('display', 'block');   //display random div  
  }, 1000);
});
```

```css
#div1 {
 background-color: rgb(246, 210, 88);
}

#div2 {
 background-color: rgb(239, 206, 197);
}

#div3 {
 background-color: rgb(136, 177, 75);
}

#div4 {
 background-color: rgb(151, 213, 224);
}

#div5 {
 background-color: rgb(239, 86, 45);
}

.divs {
 width: 300px;
 height: 300px;
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="divs" id="div1"></div>
<div class="divs" id="div2"></div>
<div class="divs" id="div3"></div>
<div class="divs" id="div4"></div>
<div class="divs" id="div5"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Ok, I figure it out, here is my solution, someone might gonna find it helpful:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    
    $('#div1').css('display', 'block');

    $('#previous').click(previousClick);
    $('#next').click(nextClick);

    let divs = $('.divs');
    let counter = 0;

    function previousClick() {

        if (counter > 0) {

            counter--;

            for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                $(divs[i]).css('display', 'none');
            }
            $(divs[counter]).css('display', 'block');
        } 
    }

    function nextClick() {

        if (counter < 4) {

            counter++;

            for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                $(divs[i]).css('display', 'none');
            }
            $(divs[counter]).css('display', 'block');
        } 
    }

});
```

```css
#div1 {
 background-color: rgb(246, 210, 88);
}

#div2 {
 background-color: rgb(239, 206, 197);
}

#div3 {
 background-color: rgb(136, 177, 75);
}

#div4 {
 background-color: rgb(151, 213, 224);
}

#div5 {
 background-color: rgb(239, 86, 45);
}

.divs {
 width: 300px;
 height: 300px;
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
   <title>Slider Exercise</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>

   <button id="previous">Previous</button>
   <button id="next">Next</button>

   <br>
   <br>

   <div class="divs" id="div1"></div>
   <div class="divs" id="div2"></div>
   <div class="divs" id="div3"></div>
   <div class="divs" id="div4"></div>
   <div class="divs" id="div5"></div>


   
   <!-- Scripts -->
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="viktor.js"></script>

  </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Instead of `.css('display', 'none');`, use `.hide()` and `.css('display', 'block);`, use `.show()` **And** instead of `$(divs[i]).css('display', 'none');` to hide them all. `$(divs).hide();` works on the whole collection. Then the comparison for `i`... Arrg. Look at my answer. That is all about syntax... Your thing is working, but could be improved.

Comment: I improved my answer to handle it with buttons instead of an interval. Please look at the syntax... How it is shorter... ;)